# fishers exact test help creating a matrix

Tags: r

I am a second year M.Sc student and I am running into a bit of a snag running my statistics.

I am trying to run a contingency table and Fishers test and I keep getting an error.

> Error in fisher.test(GAL4UAS) : if 'x' is not a matrix, 'y' must be given

If anyone can see what I have done wrong/may be missing I would really appreciate it?

This is the code:

```
setwd("/Users/Pria/Desktop/Data Analysis/")

GAL4UAS <-- data.frame(Yes=c(20,21,19),No=c(10,9,11))

GAL4UAS <- lapply(GAL4UAS, abs)

fisher.test(GAL4UAS)

fisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,2)])

fisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,3)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fisher.test()` is anticipating a matrix as an input and not a data frame. Try putting your data into a matrix. One option among several would be:

```
m <- matrix(c(20,21,19,10,9,11),nrow = 3,ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)
fisher.test(m)
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough, it worked! The only thing is that I am still getting the same error message for linesfisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,2)])

fisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,3)])

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the abs() using lapply the output is a list and not a data.frame. The apply function returns the output in a matrix format which is expected in the fisher.test(). So maybe you can try this:

```
GAL4UAS <- data.frame(Yes=c(20,21,19),No=c(10,9,11))

GAL4UAS <- apply(GAL4UAS, abs, MARGIN=c(1,2))

fisher.test(GAL4UAS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But same thing as my comment to the response above, it worked for the fisher.test but not for 
fisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,2)])

fisher.test(GAL4UAS[c(1,3)])

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks again :)